# How to download data with minio uri

Tags: minio, kubeflow

When I run simple kubeflow pipeline on minikube like first pod's output is second pod's input, data seems to be saved in minio. But I did not intend to use it. So to check the output data in minino, I got access to http://localhost:9000/ . Then I reached to login page.

When I run `kubectl get secrets` to find secret information, I could not find any minio secrets. Also minioadmin and minioadmin for Access Key and Secret Key did not work. How can I fetch data from minio uri?

I define the pipeline like this;

```py
import kfp
import kfp.components as comp
from kfp.components import load_component_from_file
example_component1_op = load_component_from_file("./pipelines/components/example_component1/example_component1.yaml")
example_component2_op = load_component_from_file("./pipelines/components/example_component2/example_component2.yaml")

@kfp.dsl.pipeline(name='example_pipeline_20220820')
def example_pipeline():
    example_component1_task = example_component1_op(
        input_1='/app/input.txt',
        input_2=8,
    )
    
    example_component2_task = example_component2_op(
        input_1=example_component1_task.outputs['output_1'],
        input_2=5,
    )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Access Key and the Secret Key.

- Access Key: `minio`
- Secret Key: `minio123`

Ref

- https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/developer_guide.md